# MacBook-Pro boots to BLACK screen; keyboard back light is OFF; fan is running; gets hot

Tags: macos, startup, performance

I was on the internet and it locked up the computer so I forced a shut-down.  But after that... it won't boot up.

- On boot it chimes
- and nothing shows on the screen.
- The keyboard back light is NOT on.
- However, the fan is running
- And if I leave it in this position for awhile the computer gets real hot.

Is this a virus I got off the internet?

I tried the options I saw to boot:

- shift
- shift+command+option
- boot up disk

Nothing gets past this problem.

Equipment:

- OS:  Sierra
- MacBook pro 2011
- 15 inch screen.
- Can't boot up to see the model#

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by trying to reset both the NVRAM and SMC using the steps below.

Before doing so, ensure you have no external hardware connected and that you're using the **built-in keyboard**.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Here’s how to reset the NVRAM on your particular MBP:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** If your MBP does log back in normally, you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

To reset the SMC on your particular MBP, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the built-in keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

After resetting both the NVRAM and SMC, try booting your computer to determine if the issue still persists. IF it does, then test the hardware as per the instructions below.

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

Your model MBP uses Apple Hardware Test. To use this, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key immediately
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** that the extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

though I would let you know I had this issue with my daughters MacBook Pro and offer a possible cause and the solution by my service centre. After I tried every “control” “command” “shift” ” option” “D”, “P”, “R” , power on option suggested on internet and a few other I made up. The problem was diagnosed as a screen panel cable issue. We could open the screen to about 70-80 deg and I could see everything, beyond that it would go blank. Needed to turn off , close screen totally open to less than 70-80 deg and it would work when we powered up again, then if we pushed the screen past the 70-80 deg it went blank again. This was enough of a fix to get my daughter out of trouble and her frustration cranky pants mood, (because of her year 11 (Australia High School) work on the computer), until we came up with a new screen. Not cheap but had to replace the screen because of a warn out cable.
Hope this helps.
Have a nice day.

Wayne